# Making CSS Drop Down Menu 2 Columns

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Long time lurker but posting for the first time. I've been searching around already and found a solution to what I'm looking to do but for some reason I'm getting a weird result.

Basically my menu has so many items that I would like to see them in 2 columns. By searching I found that I needed to make the "ul" twice as wide as the "li" and float the "li" left. It is working but now I'm getting a blank space in the 2nd row.

```
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  z-index: 597;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  background: #333333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
 *display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  text-transform: none;
  min-width: 190px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  background: #1b9bff;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #0082e7;
  border-top: 0 none;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4eb1ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li.active > a {
  background: #1b9bff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 99.5%;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #333333;
  color: #CBCBCB;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1hsakq2/1/

I'm missing something in the CSS....

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The border-top on your first-child in list is causing the 3rd list item to not fit. See the revised fiddle here where I commented it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/b1hsakq2/3/

```
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  /*border-top: 1px solid #0082e7;*/
}
```

The other option is to keep the above border-top on the first-child, but to even the height within the list, add a border-top to the other list items by adding this:

```
#cssmenu ul ul li > a {
  border-top: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bklynM for taking the time to look at it and for explaining ! Very appreciated.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works out.